# Filtered Calculation in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table which consists of the following:

> Date | Region |Revenue Type| Revenue Amount |

There are 20 Revenue Types (A,B,C....Goal), with the last type being a goal for  A, B, and C.

I'd like to be able to graph the sum of A, B, C against the Goal. The Goal would be on a Dual Axis.

Is there a way to create a calculated field for SUM(A,B,C) and contrast against the Goal in a single line graph?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could come up with is by creating one calculated field `Goal` with `[Revenue Type] = 'Goal'`. This will give you a boolean value that inidcates if it is the goal or another type.

If you drop `[date]` on columns and `[Revenue Amount]` on rows, you get one timeline. If you then drop `[goal]` on colour, you will get 2 different timelines, one for your goal and one for the sum of all the others.

If you want to have the goal as a different chart (eg. a line in front of bars), you could create 2 calculated fields: `IF [Revenue Type] = 'Goal THEN [Revenue Amount] END` and `IF [Revenue Type] != 'Goal THEN [Revenue Amount] END`

This will give you 2 measures, one for the goal, one for all the others and based on these you could create a dual axis chart.